# CGRectIntersectsRect change image on hover

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, cgrect

So I have to rects, one is product and the other a trash can. Right now I have it so you can drag products into the trash and when you release it will check for a CGRectIntersectsRect and then run the delete function on the product. I now want to make it so that when you are hovering over the trashcan the trashcan changes to a glowing trashcan (so that you know you are about to delete the item). Now I assumed this would be a simple image hover change. So I tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
UIImage *hoverImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"trashHover.png"];
[deleteItemButton setImage:hoverImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Any idea on how I could get it so that when one rect is over another we can change the image? Or should I be doing something other then CGRectIntersectsRect?

Answer (score 1):

The `UIControlStateHighlighted` state is set when the user begins the touch on that given element. The user would have to have begun the touch on the trashcan and not the dragged item. From the docs:

> Highlighted state of a control. A control enters this state when a
>   touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up
>   event. You can retrieve and set this value through the highlighted
>   property.

In order to have the trash can image while dragging another image you will have to respond to the `touchesMoved:withEvent` callback.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint buttonPoint = [self.view convertPoint:touchPoint toView:self.someButton];

        if ([self.someButton pointInside:buttonPoint withEvent:event])
        {
            [self.someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So would that be under the CGRectintersectswithRect function or totally separate? Still learning objective C.

Comment: If you're already using `CGRectIntersectsRect()` to do the hit detection you can use that instead of `pointInside:withEvent:`. I prefer the latter because you can do things like subclassing the method on the your trashcan and defining a smaller hit box (like in the case of a rounded image).

Comment: Sorry so I have no idea if you have a solution to this, but I tried your solution and I ran into an issue, the touchesMoved event is not fired if userInteractionEnabled = YES is set on the buttons. If I set it to NO I can click and move my finger over the trashcan and it highlights as I wanted, however it no longer moves the image along with my finger. (Since interaction is set to NO). And if it is set to YES it only triggers the touchesMoved one time at the start, any idea?